# Pixel binning with R5C

Tags: canon, photoshop

How can I do pixel binning with R5C's raw files or directly (ie., before writing a file), with still or video, from the camera (eg., with a specific downscaled format) or with another existing software (eg., DaVinci Resolve, Photoshop) ?

Maybe more specifically I'm considering binning as mean or sum of clusters of 2 (horizontal line or vertical line) or 4 pixels (square).

Other cluster algorithms such as bicubic, bilinear, cubic b-splines, may not be as good as binning for reducing noise while keeping sharpness by downsampling (eg., I would be considering 8k DCI to 4k DCI for the video case).

Comment: My understanding is pixel binning is physical characteristic of the sensor, not RAW characteristic.

Comment: @RomeoNinov it's none of them, you can do that yourself, it's an algorithm, it can be implemented in hardware or software, but in resampling, for general cases, it's not implemented, it's using a more general  algorithm such as bicubic. Binning is the merging of two pixels into one.

Comment: @Soleil, could you please include in your question what you've looked in so far? From your comment it seems you already know something about binning, but it's unclear what. By [edit]ing that into your question you can prevent that people suggest something that you know already doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Merging clusters of pixels into one? I did something like that using [Processing](https://processing.org) many years ago for a digital art project. But as I say, it's not fully clear to me what you are asking help with achieving.

Comment: @osullic It's in the OP: pixel binning (...)

Comment: @Soleil Yes, I can read... Your question isn't clear. Are you just trying to resize downwards? That's essentially pixel binning. I think you should give your question a once-over for explicit clarity.